# phpGrid_Lite doesnt show grid on CodeIgniter-3.1.7

Tags: php, codeigniter, continuous-integration, phpgrid

I have followed the tutorial from the official webpage https://phpgrid.com/example/phpgrid-and-codeigniter-integration/
but my view doesn't show the grid, my database is called **phpGrid** and have a table **producto**, this problem only occur with CI, because i have tested **phpGrid_Lite** without CI and works fine showing the grid.

(sorry for my bad english :))

this is my `Welcome` controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        //$this->load->view('welcome_message');

        require_once(APPPATH. 'libraries/phpGrid_Lite/conf.php'); // APPPATH is path to application folder
        $data['phpgrid'] = new C_DataGrid("SELECT * FROM producto", "id", "producto"); //$this->ci_phpgrid->example_method(3);

        $this->load->view('show_grid',$data);
    }
}
```

and here is my `show_grid.php` file

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Show Grid</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter! Show me the grid!</h1>

<div id="body">
    <?php $phpgrid->display(); ?>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

the `conf.php`

```
<?php
/**/
if (stripos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 'apps/phpgrid-custom-crm')) {
define('PHPGRID_DB_HOSTNAME', '127.0.0.1'); // database host name
define('PHPGRID_DB_USERNAME', 'root');     // database user     name
define('PHPGRID_DB_PASSWORD', ''); // database password
define('PHPGRID_DB_NAME', 'phpGrid'); // database name
define('PHPGRID_DB_TYPE', 'mysql');  // database type
define('PHPGRID_DB_CHARSET','utf8'); // ex: utf8(for mysql),AL32UTF8 (for oracle), leave blank to use the default charset
} else {
//* mysql example 
define('PHPGRID_DB_HOSTNAME','localhost'); // database host name
define('PHPGRID_DB_USERNAME', 'root');     // database user name
define('PHPGRID_DB_PASSWORD', ''); // database password
define('PHPGRID_DB_NAME', 'phpGrid'); // database name
define('PHPGRID_DB_TYPE', 'mysql');  // database type
define('PHPGRID_DB_CHARSET','utf8'); // ex: utf8(for mysql),AL32UTF8 (for         oracle), leave blank to use the default charset
}
```

and finally [this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d4Z3.png)

Answer (score 2):

Did you configure CI to use native PHP session? You may also need to [add .htaccess in the application](https://phpgrid.com/example/phpgrid-and-codeigniter-integration/) folder due to permission update in CI3.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem with CI and phpgrid Lite and this is how I got the grids to appear.
I moved the assets folder from the application/library so it is in the same folder as the application folder and the system folder.

Then I altered these parts of the controller and view.

### Controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
     require_once('assets/phpGrid_Lite/conf.php');
     $dg = new C_DataGrid("SELECT * FROM Orders", "orderNumber", "Orders"); //$this->ci_phpgrid->example_method(3);
     $dg -> set_multiselect(true);
     $dg -> enable_search(true);

     $dg->display(false);
     $data['phpgrid'] = $dg->get_display(true);

     $this->load->view('show_grid',$data);
    }

}
```

In the View  file show_grid.php

### View:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Show Grid</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter! Show me the grid!</h1>

<div id="body">
    <?= $phpgrid; ?>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this works for you.